# Запись многострочного текста в файл Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, строки, python-2.7

Есть такой код:

```
 my_str = """Hello!
          {0} medved....
          privet!"""
 buff = 'Little'     

 with open('\"{0}\"'.format(fileName), 'w') as file:
     file.writelines(my_str.format(buff))
```

Программа перестаёт работать с ошибкой:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename.

Но мод и путь верные. Есть подозрение, что многострочный текст не пишется в файл. Если это так, то как правильно его записывать?

Comment: На какой строке валится? Занесите все же имя файла в переменную и выведите его перед открытием...

Comment: В какой ОС работаете?

Comment: С правами доступа к файлу (папке где все это происходит) все нормально? Других причин не вижу, только что проверил в консоли.

Comment: @mkkik, Windows 7

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, в тексте ошибки выводится имя файла и оно валидное.

Comment: @andy.37, запускаю от админа, так что с правами доступа не должно быть проблем. К тому же, ошибка была бы тогда "Access denied".

Comment: @neo, а в Windows допустимы двойные кавычки в имени?

Comment: @mkkik, это экранирование, на случай, если путь содержит пробелы

Comment: @neo, а в имени файла, случайно, нет кавычек?

Comment: Windows вероятно не принимает имена файлов, которые начинаются и заканчиваются на кавычки. Попробуйте просто: `open(filename, 'w')`, а не `open('"'+filename+'"','w')`. (здесь нет cmd.exe, поэтому кавычки вероятно ни к чему).

Comment: @jfs, да, там был косяк в том, что в начале пути добавлялась 1 кавычка, так как путь вырезается с помощью **os.path.dirname()**, внезапно он режет путь до последнего слэша и не чистит кавычку в начале пути. Как-то грустненько. В итоге, когда избавился от всех кавычек - заработало.

Comment: @neo: путь, который вы передаёте в `os.path.dirname()` также не должен содержать никаких кавычек (`dirname()` также не использует `cmd.exe`). Если нашли решение проблемы, то оформите это ввиде ответа, чтобы это могло другим помочь -- [это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема не в том, что многострочный текст не пишется в файл.

Двойные кавычки в ОС Windows нельзя использовать в пути и имени файла.

См. [справку MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx) (цитата немного поправлена, т.к. перевод сделан с помощью машинного перевода):

> Например в настольных системах, работающих под управлением Windows, недопустимые символы пути могут включать символы ASCII и Юникода 1 до 31, а также ***кавычек (`"`)***, меньше (`<`), больше (`>`), вертикальная черта (`|`), *backspace* (`\b`), *null* (`\0`) и табуляция (`\t`).

Используйте

```
with open(fileName, 'w') as file:
```